# Overlapping date range MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I have the following data;

```
ID  startDate               endDate
-----------------------------------------------
1   2010-03-01 10:00:00     2010-03-01 12:00:00
2   2010-03-01 12:30:00     2010-03-01 15:30:00
3   2010-03-01 15:30:00     2010-03-01 18:30:00
```

What I want to do is check that a start and end date don't fall inside the startDate and endDate ranges in my data.

So for example, the following would be OK;

```
startDate               endDate
-----------------------------------------------
2010-03-01 12:00:00     2010-03-01 12:30:00
2010-03-01 18:30:00     2010-03-01 21:00:00
```

but the following dates would fail, as they would overlap;

```
startDate               endDate
-----------------------------------------------
2010-03-01 09:00:00     2010-03-01 13:00:00 (overlaps ID 1)
2010-03-01 10:30:00     2010-03-01 11:00:00 (overlaps ID 1)
2010-03-01 18:00:00     2010-03-01 19:00:00 (overlaps ID 3)
```

I'm pulling my hair out because I can get one or two of the above 3 test date ranges to fail but not all of them.

I am using MySQL.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A query to select overlaps (I'd name the columns startTime & endTime though, as Time seems important...):

```
WHERE 
<start> < endDate
AND
<end> > startDate
```

Comment: This is almost what I had bar the last line (which I believe you added in during your edit)!  Thanks, you saved me a headache!

Comment: I edited another answer in, care to see whether that much shorter solution is OK?

Comment: Sorry, do you mean just "WHERE <start> < endDate AND <end> > startDate" ?

Comment: Yes. that's what I meant. Don't let the apparent simplicity fool you, I think it'll work.

Comment: Logically, they should be the same, so if one works the other also works (or they both fail / have the same bug)

Comment: Your short answer is correct, you should remove the longer one to make it clearer/more obvious.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not the best method, but maybe you can gleam something from this example.  This would return a result only if they overlapped, and I would probably use this in a `not exists` query.

```
select 1 from myTable
where 
('03/01/2010 09:00:00' between startDate and endDate)
or
('03/01/2010 13:00:00' between startDate and endDate)
or 
(startDate between '03/01/2010 09:00:00' and '03/01/2010 13:00:00')
or
(endDate between '03/01/2010 09:00:00' and '03/01/2010 13:00:00')
```

Per Wrikken's answer, you probably need to check that the values aren't exact matches as well.

Answer (score 0):

Overlapping entries:

```
SELECT t1.Id, t2.Id, t1.StartDate, t1.EndDate, t2.StartDate, t2.EndDate
FROM Table t1, Table t2
WHERE t1.ID <> t2.Id
AND (t1.StartDate between t2.StartDate and t2.EndDate
    OR
     t1.EndDate between  t2.StartDate and t2.EndDate)
```